структура в c++/cli
ref struct MyStruct
{
    int* DAYRecivied = Convert::ToInt32(textBoxDAY->Text);
    int *MONTHRecivied = Convert::ToInt32(textBoxMONTH->Text);
    int *YEARRecivied = Convert::ToInt32(textBoxYEAR->Text);
    String^ dayweek = textBoxDAYWEEK->Text;
};

сделал я такую структуру в h файле после public ref my form, компилятор ругается на необъявленные идентификаторы, оно и понятно ведь они объявляются после нажатия на кнопку, а в этих полях будет что либо написано, на сколько я понимаю, тогда как мне их объявить по умолчанию и главное где?


Значения убери.
Инты - не указатели.


без интов это объявление не содержит спецификатор типа

Все разобрался, моя ахиллесова пята в неполном понимании структур и классов, спасибо за помощь!
